# How to get to Pompeii, Herculaneum, Vesuvius from Naples with public transport

Tags: italy, transportation, naples, pompeii

I'm planning on being in Naples on September 19 and 20 and I'd like to visit Pompeii and Herculaneum and Mount Vesuvius.

According to Google Maps Mount Vesuvius [is about 11mi away from Pompeii](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mount+Vesuvius,+Ottaviano,+Metropolitan+City+of+Naples,+Italy/80045+Pompeii,+Metropolitan+City+of+Naples,+Italy/@40.7845715,14.4295849,13z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x133ba508f1413feb:0x9cbfa7aa9376793d!2m2!1d14.4289058!2d40.822383!1m5!1m1!1s0x133bbc95914ba4ef:0xd2d18a72aeb414a4!2m2!1d14.4989344!2d40.7461572!3e2?shorturl=1), one way. I like walking but 22mi total seems like a bit much. What options exist for getting closer to the peak?

If public transit isn't an option, how readily available are taxis in Pompeii or Herculaneum, and how close could they get me to the peak?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't say what your starting point is, so let's do it from Naples, using Rome2Rio.com.

Herculaneum, Ercolano in Italian:
[CTP](http://www.ctp.na.it/percorsi.asp?TS=ORDINARIO) bus leaves hourly, get off at San Giorgio a Cremano, takes 10 minutes.

Vesuvius (Vesuvio):
[Vesuvio Express](http://www.vesuvioexpress.info/) on demand, from Piazza San Pasquale, takes 40 minutes; connects you from Ercolano to the cone of Vesuvio.

You can hike the up the cone; it takes about 30 minutes to get up, the same to get down.

Pompeii (one 'i' in Italian: Pompei):
[Trenitalia](http://orario.trenitalia.com/b2c/npp_price_input_it.jsp?lang=en&stazin=Napoli%20Piazza%20Garibaldi&stazout=Pompei&datag=%7Bday%7D&datam=%7Bmonth%7D&dataa=%7Byear%7D&timsh=%7Bhour%7D&timsm=%7Bminute%7D&nreq=5&sort=0&car=0), 40 minutes, leaves every 30 minutes
[Sita Sud](http://www.sitasudtrasporti.it/orari) bus, every 2 hours, takes 42 minutes
[Sulga](http://www.sulga.it/autolinee.php) bus, once daily

Taxis are available in Herculaneum, particularly in the area of the train station, as well as from the Pompeii Scavi station.

Comment: I recently took the train from Napoli to Pompei, and would add that the Napoli train station is fairly huge & complex and multiple other trains will arrive at the same place, so I would expect to take 20-50 minutes to find & understand how to identify the right train.

Comment: @Dronz agreed; it is. It helps that I speak Italian, although not Napoletano. It also helps to check in advance on Trenitalia, so that you know the train number, at least.

Comment: Yes, I speak Italian too, but somehow had to speak to three staff and one very helpful local before I really knew which train to catch. :) (But it was memorable and I got to see part of how huge that place is - there's a kind of incredible staircase going down what seems like 8 levels to the commuter trains that don't go to Pompei. ;-) )